# How can I reliably detect network connection drops (WLAN)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-networking

I have a customer who has an unstable WLAN network. He has installed my Windows database application (based on Firebird), but the WLAN connection drops lead to inconveniences for this customer. I advised to stabilize the network or to switch to an ethernet network.

But the customer (using Win7) believes his WLAN network is stable. Is there a possibility to detect (prove) short time network connection drops (for instance via log files or by an external tool)?

Comment: A tool pinging some host once in a couple of minutes would be a possibility.

Comment: No, this are very short time drops. If they use WLAN for internet surfing, they wont even notice. Therefore they don't believe me. But my database connections definitively get cut.